# Why is 32.32 a double, and not a float?

Tags: c#

This is my C# code which generates two instances(**c1**,**c2**) of type **Circle**.

```
using System;
namespace ClassCircle
{
    class Circle
    {
        float radius;
        public Circle(float n)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("a circle of radius {0} has been created",n);
            radius = n;
        }
        public double getArea()
        {
            double area = Math.PI * radius * radius;
            return area;
        }
        public double getPerimeter()
        {
            double peri = 2 * Math.PI * radius;
            return peri;
        }
        public void printInfo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Perimeter = {0}", getPerimeter());
            Console.WriteLine("Area = {0}", getArea());
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", Math.PI.GetType());
            Circle c1 = new Circle(9);
            Circle c2 = new Circle(32.32);
            Console.WriteLine("data of c1");
            c1.printInfo();
            Console.WriteLine("data of c2");
            c2.printInfo();
            //Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

the error is [image]

which is where the second instance **c2** is being created. 
The description says '*cannot convert from double to float*'. I can't understand, my parameter is 32.32 which i believe is a float.

Comment: Use `32.32f`. Without that `f` (or `F`) it is interpreted as a `double`.

Comment: For future reference, this title is **really** undescriptive. Something like "Why is 32.32 a double, and not a float?" would be much better. (Edited to fix, please write better titles in the future).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing it a `double` and it wants a `float`. You need to enter the number as `32.32f` for it to be valid, otherwise it assumes `double` for decimal numbers.

Answer (score 9):

When you write a decimal literal (such as `32.32`) it is automatically assumed by the compiler to be a double.

You need to explicitly say it is a float, like so:

```
32.32f
```

Or

```
(float)32.32
```

Note that your other line passes the integer literal `9` which *is* implicitly castable to a `float` (`double` does not implicitly cast to anything, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx)) so it compiles.

Answer (score 1):

To define a value as a float you need to suffix it with `f` - see this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/b1e65aza.aspx) article.

In your case you'd want to use:

```
Circle c2 = new Circle(32.32f);
```